# How do I create a dataframe from two dictionaries with values on same row?

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

Let's say I have two dictionaries:

```
a = {'col1':1, 'col2':2}
b = {'col3':3, 'col4':4}
```

When I try to create a dataframe via:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([a,b])
```

I get a dataframe with dictionary a on row 0, and dictionary b on row 1. I want them both on the same row.

I get this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
 1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
 NaN  NaN  3.0  4.0
```

But I want this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
 1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us merge the `dict` first

```
df=pd.DataFrame({**a,**b},index=[0])
df
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2     3     4
```